# How to use <webview> methods inside a react component

Tags: reactjs, webview, electron

I am building a dashboard that links to various servers using ReactJS and electron. Now in a page I have a button and when it is clicked it renders a "webview" in the application using  tag but i do not get the whole page as it needs some additional headers like langauge. I saw in the official documentation here  https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/ that for using webview methods we first have to load the webview element but I tried all the possibilities that I had in my mind but couldnt come up with a solution.

Please if anyone can let me know where and how should I load the webview element and how to use the webview methods inside the component, really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the ref of webview and initially don't load any url

```
<WebView autosize={true} ref={(input) => { this.webview = input; }} src="data:text/plain" />
```

in your componentDidUpdate() load url with extra headers

```
if (this.webview) {
  this.webview.loadUrl(url, {
    extraHeaders: ""
  });
}
```